# gdb.lookup_type returns invalid type with boost::multi_index_container

Tags: gdb, boost-multi-index, pretty-print

I'm using gdb-7.5, on RHEL 6, compiled with gcc-4.7.2. I'm trying to
write a pretty printer for `boost::multi_index` and ran into problems
with `gdb.lookup_type`.

Below given code has the following declaration.

```
TestSet ts;
```

Now, at the gdb command prompt, I'm performing the following
operations (in python)

```
gdb >> python

set_value = gdb.parse_and_eval('ts')
set_type = set_value.type.strip_typedefs()
t1 = set_type.template_argument(0) # Test
t2 = set_type.template_argument(1) # boost::mult_index::indexed_by ....
t3 = set_type.template_argument(2) # std::allocator<Test>
node_type = gdb.lookup_type('boost::multi_index::detail::multi_index_node_type < %s, %s, %s >::type' % (t1, t2, t3))
base = gdb.lookup_type ('boost::multi_index::detail::multi_index_base_type < %s, %s, %s >::type' % (t1, t2, t3))
allocator = gdb.lookup_type('boost::detail::allocator::rebind_to<%s, %s>::type' % (t3, node_type))
end
```

I'm getting the node_type correctly. But gdb is unable to get types
for 'base' and 'allocator'.

The error for base

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
gdb.error: No type named boost::detail::multi_index_base_type < Test,
boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Test,
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
>, &Test::s>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>
, boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<int,
mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_i
ndex::member<Test, int, &Test::i>, mpl_::na>,
boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Test,
float, &Test::f>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
mpl_::na, mpl_::na
, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>,
std::allocator<Test> >::type.
Error while executing Python code.
```

and a similar error for 'allocator'.
As `boost::multi_index_container` is derived from
`boost::detail::multi_index_base_type`, I'm expecting gdb to return a
valid type for the same.

Am I missing something here. ?
I've posted the same question in gdb mailing list but there was no answer.

The code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key_extractors.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using namespace boost;

struct Test
{ 
  Test (const string& ps, int pi, float pf)
    : s(ps), i(pi), f(pf)
  {
  }

  string s;
  int i;
  float f;
};

typedef multi_index_container <
  Test,
  indexed_by <
    ordered_unique < member <Test, string, &Test::s> >,
    ordered_unique < tag<int>,  member <Test, int, &Test::i> >,
    ordered_unique < member <Test, float, &Test::f> >
    >
  > TestSet;

int main(void)
{ 
  TestSet ts;
  ts.insert(Test("ABCDEF", 10, 1.0f));
  ts.insert(Test("Some String", 5, 2.0f));
  ts.insert(Test("PQRXYZ", 7, 0.3f));

  return 0;
}
```

Surya

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to find out whether this type actually does exist.  One way would be to dig through the "readelf -wi" output.  This dumps the DWARF information for your program.  However, it is likely to be very large, and so it may take a while.

If it exists in the DWARF then I would debug gdb to see what is going wrong.

If it isn't in the DWARF then it may be a compiler error, or just wrong compilation arguments.